# Chome browser onbeforeunload event is failed to show up the warning popup but works fine if we open chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, onbeforeunload

I would like to show up the browser warning popup dialog when user close the browser by clicking x button.

Code snippet:

window.onbeforeunload = confirmMessage;  //Show warning popup message when user close the page.       
        function confirmMessage() {                 
                    var message = "Do you want to close the page?";
                    return message;
                }

It working fine only when I keep open the Chrome Dev Tools window( F12).

If i run code with out chrome Dev Tools opened it dont show up the warning poup message( leave app?..)

Anyone knows why is that behavior that its not working as expected when we dont open the chrome Dev Tools?

Popup message.
[image]

Comment: Modern Chrome requires real user interaction in that tab/frame otherwise it ignores the message in beforeunload.

Comment: Thanks for your information!